# ¿El acumulador de for ... in en Javascript no es un número? ¿Por qué debo usar parseInt() si quiero mostrar el valor de i+1?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, buenas-prácticas

Estoy leyendo un array de objetos JSON con `for ... in` de Javascript. Y ocurre algo que me llama la atención. Yo quiero usar el índice (de base `0`) para mostrar en qué fila estoy en la lectura, pero empezando por `1`, no por `0`. Entonces intento **mostrar un suma de `i + 1` dentro del bucle** (quiero sumar para mostrar `i+1` en pantalla, no se trata de modificar `i`). Pero el comportamiento es como si `i` fuese un string:

```js
var mData=`[
   {
      "k1":"v1.1",
      "k2":"v1.2"
   },
   {
      "k1":"v2.1",
      "k2":"v2.2"
   },
   {
      "k1":"v3.1",
      "k2":"v3.2"
   }
]`;

var mJson=JSON.parse(mData);
for (i in mJson){
  console.log(`Data ${i+1}\n`);
  console.log(`\tk1: ${mJson[i].k1} \n\tk2: ${mJson[i].k2}`);
}
```

Como pueden ver, me muestra `Data01, Data11, Data21`.

Pero si uso `parseInt()` sí funciona:

---

```js
var mData=`[
   {
      "k1":"v1.1",
      "k2":"v1.2"
   },
   {
      "k1":"v2.1",
      "k2":"v2.2"
   },
   {
      "k1":"v3.1",
      "k2":"v3.2"
   }
]`;

var mJson=JSON.parse(mData);
var x=0;
for (i in mJson){
  x=i;
  console.log(`Data ${parseInt(i)+1}\n`);
  console.log(`\tk1: ${mJson[i].k1} \n\tk2: ${mJson[i].k2}`);
}
```

Entonces, ¿`i` es un String u otro tipo de dato? ¿Por qué no es un entero siendo que es un contador? ¿Habría otra forma de hacer lo que quiero, **mostrar el valor de `i` más uno, OJO, sin modificar `i` en su valor?

Comment: Una sugerencia ${variable + 1} parece actuar como un operador de cadena en el primer caso, mientras que en el segundo, ${parseInt(i)+1} al no haber variable explícita y usar una función opera sobre el resultado. Prueba en el primero a hacer una línea antes `j=i+1;` y en la salida pones `${j}` eso nos saca de la duda acerca de si **i** es tomado como cadena en el primer caso.

Comment: perdona la terrible redacción de la sugerencia

Comment: `i` siempre sera string por defecto, porque la iteracion depende la implementacion, por lo que `i` puede ser un `numero,string,etc`, si quieres un valor indice `numerico`, esta `for, for...of y forEach()`

Comment: puedes hacer un `console.log(`Data ${+i+1}\n`);` donde el simbolo `+` que predece a la variable hace un mejor cast en base al tipo ejemplo: `parseInt( "1.12")+1` resutado `2` pero con `+i+1` seria `2.12`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Entonces, ¿i es un String u otro tipo de dato?

Es un string.

> ¿Por qué no es un entero siendo que es un contador?

No es un contador. El uso de `for...in` es recorrer las propiedades de un objeto, así que en la variable `i` se guarda el nombre de la propiedad, de ahí su tipo string.

> ¿Habría otra forma de hacer lo que quiero, **mostrar el valor de i más
> uno, OJO, sin modificar i en su valor?

Sí, con un `forEach()`

```js
var mData=`[
   {
      "k1":"v1.1",
      "k2":"v1.2"
   },
   {
      "k1":"v2.1",
      "k2":"v2.2"
   },
   {
      "k1":"v3.1",
      "k2":"v3.2"
   }
]`;

var mJson=JSON.parse(mData);

mJson.forEach((elemento,i)=>{

  console.log(`Data ${i+1}\n`);
  console.log(`\tk1: ${elemento.k1} \n\tk2: ${elemento.k2}`);

});
```

[Referencia for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in)

Comment: Gracias por tu excelente respuesta. Debí haber leído la doc antes. Además, `for ... in` no es fiable para el uso que quiero darle aquí, por esto que dice la doc: *«Debido a que el orden de iteración depende de la implementación, es posible que la iteración sobre un arreglo **no visite los elementos en un orden coherente**. Por lo tanto, es mejor usar un bucle for con un índice numérico (o `Array.prototype.forEach()` o el bucle `for...of`) cuando se itera sobre arreglos donde **el orden de acceso es importante**.»*